# ZF2 router not working on staging

Tags: apache, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

So I have a ZF2 project running locally and it works great. When I set it up on a staging server I ran into a routing problem. It routes "/" to the proper controller but when visiting, say "/blog" it will look for an actual folder and return the following error:

```
The requested URL /blog was not found on this server.
```

Normally if it didn't match any defined routes ZF2 would return an error saying the that the URL could not be matched with routing. But it appears as though this is breaking out of the entire application. Has anyone else ran into similar problems/found a fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your whole .htaccess file with following code.

## this will work surely.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$

RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Or you can visit this link for updated details. [Htaccess file for any project](https://vrkansagara.in/blog/post/htaccess-file-any-project)

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rules are not being used. If you're using Apache, either you didn't upload your `.htaccess` file to your staging server, or your staging server is not configured to read `.htaccess` files. At the moment, requests are not even reaching your Zend Framework app because your web server isn't configured to send them there.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if this can solve your doubt, but in the past I had almost the same problem as you. Here's the part of routing that I use in my module.config.php:

**For 'admin' module, for example:**

```
<?php 
...
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'admin' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/admin',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '[/:controller[/:action[/id/:id]]][/]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

**Or, for the main module:**

```
<?php
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '[:controller[/:action[/id/:id]]][/]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```